# Vercel x-forwarded-for IP address changes when app first loads, from when client makes an API call?

Tags: vercel, next.js13, request-headers

## Context

I'm building a very simple Blog app. There is no authentication. Each user is identified by their IP address (which is stored in DB) to provide a personalised experience like bookmarking posts, commenting, liking, etc...

#### app/layout (server)

In my root layout, I call DB to fetch data related to the user. Note, that this runs immediately as the user lands on the page.

```
export default async function RootLayout(props: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const user = await getUser()
  const store = { user }
  ...
}
```

#### server/getUser.ts (server)

This function makes DB calls. However, before we call, we need to get the user IP address from the `headers.get('x-forwarded-for')`.

```
export default async function getUser() {
  const { id: userId } = getUserId()
  ...
}
```

### server/getUserId.ts (server)

This simply extracts the IP address from the headers.

```
export function getUserId() {
  const headers = NextHeaders()

  const fallback = '171.23.136.120' // my Ip address

  // vercel exposes the ip
  let ip = headers.get('x-forwarded-for')

  return {
    id: ip ?? fallback,
  }
}
```

## Problem

When the user lands on the site. The app tries to get all the information about the user in SSR (if exists in DB), e.g. list of bookmarks, likes, comments, etc... and render it in UI.

However, the IP address that is returned from the headers is different than when the user makes an API call. e.g. button click to bookmark a post.

[image]

I'm confused about why that's the case, and how I can fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question has to be asked: have you ruled out the possibility that you're logging interactions from two truly different users?

---

The `X-Forwarded-For` header is quite a bit more complicated than you might think.

1. This header only exists if the reverse proxy / load balancer implements it. It's superseded by the new `Forwarded` header. In your case, this probably isn't the issue because you know you're deployed on Vercel and you do get a value in this header.
2. There can be multiple copies of this same header in the request. How does your `NextHeaders` object deal with this? Does it combine all of them into an array of strings? Does it silently override earlier entries with later ones?
3. There can be multiple comma-separated values in each instance of this header. This represents `client, proxy1, proxy2...` Are you handling this?

There are far, far more considerations as well, particularly if you're using this for any kind of security. The whole page on MDN is worth reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

### To handle multiple header entries:

> There are two ways of making this single list:
>
> - join the X-Forwarded-For full header values with commas and then split by comma into a list, or
> - split each X-Forwarded-For header by comma into lists and then join the lists

## Selecting the IP

If you *really* care about doing this right, the MDN page offers two options:

When choosing the first trustworthy X-Forwarded-For client IP address, additional configuration is required. There are two common methods:

> - Trusted proxy count: The count of reverse proxies between the internet
>   and the server is configured. The X-Forwarded-For IP list is searched
>   from the rightmost by that count minus one. (For example, if there is
>   only one reverse proxy, that proxy will add the client's IP address,
>   so the rightmost address should be used. If there are three reverse
>   proxies, the last two IP addresses will be internal.)
> - Trusted proxy
>   list: The IPs or IP ranges of the trusted reverse proxies are
>   configured. The X-Forwarded-For IP list is searched from the
>   rightmost, skipping all addresses that are on the trusted proxy list.
>   The first non-matching address is the target address.

But most people just select the left-most (first) value, which *should* be the client IP in most cases.

---

You may want to use a 3rd party library (eg, https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) which should handle all of these cases for you (except it won't be able to select a proper trustworthy IP, and will just use the first value).

However, I have to say, using client IP to identify a user is not a good idea. A single university may have thousands of users on the same public IP.

---

tl;dr not sure why you're experiencing what you are, but likely candidates are measurement errors (ie, it's two different users) or improper handling of the X-Forwarded-For header.

P.S. should probably block out those IP addresses. It's probably yours, and you wouldn't want to dox yourself.